# SVG Move group to other group

Tags: php, xml, svg

Want to move a group into another group, but on some way it ends up in a huge execution time, and the script is never ending. the problem is in the foreach loop rest function ok. I don't see any mistake

```
<?php
// fouten laten zien
error_reporting(~0); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

// test bestand
$bestand = "00000000346.svg";

// maak nieuwe dom
$dom = new DOMDocument; 

// laat svg in dom
$dom->load($bestand);

// krijg svg element
$svg = $dom->getElementsByTagName("svg")->item(0);

// toevoegen link attribute
$svg->setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

// maak script tag
$script = $dom->createElement("script");

// zet script link
$script->setAttribute("xlink:href", "svg_zoom_pan.js");

// toevoegen aan svg
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($script);

// maak groep tag
$svgroot = $dom->createElement("g");

// zet een id
$svgroot->setAttribute("id", "svgroot");

// toevoegen aan svg
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($svgroot);

// krijg alle groepen
$groups = $dom->getElementsByTagName("g");

// doorloop groepen
foreach($groups as $group) {

    if($group->getAttribute("id") != "svgroot") {

        // clone groep
        $cloned = $group->cloneNode(true);

        // toevoegen aan svgroot groep  
        $dom->getElementById("svgroot")->appendChild($cloned);

    }
}

// opslaan bestand
$dom->save("svg_" . $bestand);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByTagName` returns a live list of nodes. That means that when you add more groups to your document the variable `$groups` will be updated to contain those new groups.

Since you are looping over the live list of  elements and adding one more  element in each iteration, the live list be longer and the loop will never end.